# UIWebView does not scale content to fit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a webview which is the top window in the hierarchy and has been declared as shown below. However, it does not scale pages to fit. Pages are top left aligned, but are not scaled, despite the scalesPageToFit property being set to YES. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
webLookupView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 63, 289, 327)];
webLookupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
webLookupView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
webLookupView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have subsequently discovered that some web pages are correctly scaled, but some are not. For  web pages which are not properly scaled, javascript can be used to control zooming as follows:

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
[webLookupView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

Comment: the problem with that method is that I can see it loads the page in the actual size, and a second later it updates itself with the right size... it looks not good. Do you have another solution?

Comment: unfortunately I do not but I can suggest that you hide the webview until the zooming has been done.

Comment: CSS scaling are not suitable for many sites, so ```[scroll setZoomScale:animated:]``` is preferred, but you need to validate zoom to be in proper range! Seems like a bug in ```UIWebView``` class or strange behaviour. Please, check my comment above :)

Answer (score 36):

iOS5 gives a better solution

call this from webViewDidFinishLoad

```
- (void)zoomToFit
{ 
    if ([theWebView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)])
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [theWebView scrollView];

        float zoom = theWebView.bounds.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = zoom;
        [scrollView setZoomScale:zoom animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for me. The method webViewDidFinishLoad is being invoked, but it doesn't influence the size

Comment: Hi

it works, be we have time to see original size, before the scale append.  any way to get this done before?

Comment: You'll also need to validate manually zoom range! I think that's the key :)

```scroll.zoomScale = MIN(MAX(zoom, scroll.minimumZoomScale), scroll.maximumZoomScale)```

Comment: worked, but "Scales pages to fit" on webview needs to be checked.

Comment: It does not work well for me as it seems the scrollview of the webview does not fix the contentsize. I can scroll to black areas...

Comment: @confusedvorlon Awesome Answer.....scalestopages and content mode property didn't work for me but this did. device iPhone 4S, 5, 6, 6plus all having iOS 8.0+

Comment: This is great, but right after it scales, it pops back to the previous size.  Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't.  Someone else did.  Still don't know why it happened.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the below code:

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

in `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView method`
or `viewDidLoad`

Comment: or in Interface Builder :)

Comment: It only works in viewDidLoad, not webViewDidFinishLoad: (at least for me)

Answer (score 17):

If you have access to the html you are loading you can chuck the following meta tag in the header :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Answer (score 10):

in Swift2

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Or just tick Scales page to fit in storyboard or xib in Attribute Inspector of webview.

Answer (score 2):

My solution in swift:

"Scales pages to fit" on webView needs to be checked in interface builder.

Use UIWebViewDelegate.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let zoom = webView.bounds.size.width / webView.scrollView.contentSize.width
    webView.scrollView.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As [mprivate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281407/mprivat) mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10702542/2780252) you can update the zoom level of the UIWebView.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
  CGSize contentSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
  CGSize viewSize = theWebView.bounds.size;

  float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

  theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
  theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
  theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;  
}
```

Another way of achieving this would be injecting js code on the webViewDidFinishLoad as [RunLoop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172131/runloop) says.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  CGFloat scale = 0.8; // the scale factor that works for you 
  NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;",scale];
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anybody looking for `WKWebView` answer, please try the below code:

```
extension YourViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jscript)
    }
}
```

Remember to set the `navigationDelegate` of the Webview.

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

For *Swift 3*, using **RunLoop**'s effective answer:

`self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;")`

Answer (score 1):

In xCode 8.3.3, go to the storyboard of the view/scene where the web view is located and check Scale Page to Fit in the attributes inspector section . Also select Scale to Fill as the content mode.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your ViewController's **viewDidLoad**

```
[self.myWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                   self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                   self.view.frame.size.width,
                                   self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

- I also have the webview set to "scalePageToFit" and viewmode set to "Aspect Fit" in my Storyboard.

Comment: This solution is wrong, and event then code could be simplified to ```self.myWebView.frame = self.view.bounds```

Answer (score -7):

There is "Scale To Fit" option in interface builder, so it should be something programatic to do the same.

Comment: The OP knows this already, they are using the relevant property in the code in their question.