# Force UIWebView Zoom Out?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, scale

I have really small UIWebViews being used, approx. 100x150 in size, so pretty small! Because of this, Scales to fit page is no use!

So when my UIWebView is so small, is it possible to have the web page scale down so it fits the view?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511707/uiwebview-does-not-scale-content-to-fit)

Comment: No such luck, doesn't work sadly.