# UIWebview scalesPageToFit doesn't work perfectly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using a small `UIWebView`, and `scalesPageToFit` doesn't work correctly for some url.  (look like it cannot resize at 100%. (but if i zoom out the webview manually(gesture), it work!

```
view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 400.0f)];
webViewT = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
webViewT.delegate = self;
webViewT.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
[webViewT loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Please note that i've found a solution:(below work, BUT I have the time to see a "resize"

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewT {  
    if ([theWebView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)])
    {
        UIScrollView *scroll=[theWebView scrollView];

        float zoom=theWebView.bounds.size.width/scroll.contentSize.width;
        [scroll setZoomScale:zoom animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Any idea?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView does not scale content to fit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511707/uiwebview-does-not-scale-content-to-fit)

Answer (score 0):

In Some of cases this types of problem Generated. At that time java script use for control of Zoom of `UIWebView`, use following code.

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
[webLookupView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

**Other way is**

Refer this Answer [UIWebView does not scale content to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511707/uiwebview-does-not-scale-content-to-fit/11367804#11367804)