# Xcode 5 webpage won't fill to UIwebview

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

I can't manage to make the web page to load to fit the web view. I selected the Scale pages to fit and no result. Also tried programmatically with scalepagetofit=YES and nothing happened. Please let me know any other things I could try. It's a url parsed, I get the page loaded so the link works. I just can't figure out how to scale it to the view.

Comment: what website are you trying to load? is it mobile friendly?

Comment: Try answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511707/uiwebview-does-not-scale-content-to-fit

Comment: no, it's not mobile friendly. it's a news website.

Comment: thank you all. The solution was to contact the website developer and ask to add resizing for mobile (mobile friendly). None of the code programming or options in Xcode couldn't solve this issue.