# PayPal web page does not size properly in a modal UIWebView on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, paypal, uiwebview, modalviewcontroller

I display the PayPal login web page in a UIWebView. The UIWebView is displayed modally in a view controller. The modal view uses the form sheet presentation style.

The web page does not size properly because the viewport in the html is set to the device width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

Does anyone have a solution to fix the size of the web page?

See screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4xq3f4e02dowkd/iOS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_4_Feb_2015_16_34_25.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Device-width is not going to work for the modal.  Try:`<meta name="viewport" content="width:540, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you of replying. The html comes from the PayPal website so I would not be able to change the viewport without running javascript in the web view. I would prefer not to run additional scripts in the web view.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and the following code finally set PayPal to the correct size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367804/2126233

You also need this code: `[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];`