# WKWebView - content not fitting after magnification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, wkwebview

I’m experiencing a problem with a `WKWebView` on setting the magnification property.

I expecting the content to resize to fit like it does in Safari. But I can’t achieve this. When setting the magnification to a value less than 1.0 is the following.

[image]

The extra space is not used and a margin occurs. In Safari zooming out results in smaller text and image size but the extra space is actually used.

[image]

I'm using InterfaceBuild with XIB files wire up the view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, I enable magnification in `viewDidLoad`.

```
webView.allowsMagnification = YES;
```

I also tried the following with no success:

```
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
webView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
webView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
```

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you can use auto layout. It's much easier. Just add 4 margin layouts: top, left, bottom and right. should be straight forward

Comment: Thx Tai, I tried Auto Layout but it didn't change anything ... get the same result. Resizing the window works fine in both cases as long as I don't zoom in or out.

Comment: how do you zoom in and out? btw

Comment: To zoom I set the magnification property of the WKWebView.

Comment: Did you try to load another website? If it loads fine, it just might be the website it is. If the website has the viewport meta tag in the header tag like this, `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />`, it should work.
I also tried loading apple.com with WKWebview, setting magnification to 0.3 and it looked good.

Comment: Hi Tai! Yes I tried different websites and also experimented with different viewport configurations. Is it possible for you to post your demo project?

Comment: if let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/") {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            webview.load(urlRequest)
            webview.navigationDelegate = self
            webview.magnification = 0.2
        }

Comment: not sure how you implemented it

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `WKWebView`'s magnification property doesn't do what you think it does. What it does is that it scales the rendered page as a whole (think taking a bitmap or image and resizing it).

What you want is the dynamic scaling capability that Safari (and other browsers) have, generally referred to as "zooming". This is different from `magnification`, as it scales the *layout* of the page. This scales up or down the font sizes, element sizes, and so on, of a page individually.

There's no native (public) API to zoom a page like Safari does, but you can do pretty much the same thing by taking advantage of the CSS [`zoom` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom). Here's an extension that does just that:

```swift
extension WKWebView {

    func zoom(to zoomAmount: CGFloat) {
        evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.zoom = '\(zoomAmount)'", completionHandler: nil)
    }

}
```

It can be used like this:

```swift
webView.zoom(to: 0.9)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't cause the layout to update, just makes things smaller. it's not the same as pressing Cmd-+/- in Safari or chrome

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This functions almost identically to `CMD` `+` or `CMD` `-`. (You will need to adjust the value in `zoom(to:)`, of course)

Comment: Yes, I've done that but for responsive websites it doesn't relayout the content, just makes it smaller. eg a mobile sized layout doesn't become a desktop layout

Comment: @Jonathan. Oh, that's different, but I understand what you were looking for now. Your solution is probably the best (and only) way to do this.

Comment: Don't forget to apply this after successful navigation if your url has immediate navigation after loading in `webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation`

Answer (score 3):

To get as close to what Cmd +/- does in Safari/Chrome I increase the frame of the WKWebView and then transform the layer in the inverse:

```
    var zoomLevel: CGFloat = 1

    private func didTapZoomOut() {
        zoomLevel -= 0.2
        needsLayout = true
    }

    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        webView.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width * (1/zoomLevel), height: frame.height * (1/zoomLevel))
        webView.layer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(zoomLevel, zoomLevel, 1)
    }
```

This also causes the scrollbar to shrink but for my use case this isn't important.

Answer (score 2):

@mattsven answer seems to be the right one.Here's the objective c variant of his solution:

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
[[wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:jsCommand completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
if(error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    return;
}

NSLog(@" Success");
}];
```

It seems that WKWebView doesn't has a [scalePagesToFit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617950-scalespagetofit?language=objc) as UIWebView of iOS.

References.[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295277/wkwebview-equivalent-for-uiwebviews-scalespagetofit) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511707/uiwebview-does-not-scale-content-to-fit)